# why does a form behaviour change depending of the controls order?

Tags: html, jsp

There is somthing in my code that I did not understand yesterday.
It has to do with a JSP page.
This JSP page contains a form which has:
- 2 submut buttons (with the same name attribute but a different value attribute)
- a hidden field which has the same name attribute than the 2 buttons but a different value attribute.

Why am I doing this? Because I need to give users 3 different ways to submit the form. On submit, the form calls a servlet which will determine the value of the concerned parameter and will make the appropriate actions.

The hidden field value is actually set when I select an entry into a list, via a javascript function (working as expected).

code of the JSP form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal text-left" id = "form" action="SubmitMainForm" method="get">
    <input type="hidden"  id="listbox_ii" name = "sender_control">
...
    <button type="submit" name = "sender_control" id = "button_search" value = "button_search" class="btn btn-default col-xs-4">Rechercher</button>
                        <button type="submit" name = "sender_control" id = "button_delete" value = "button_delete" class="btn btn-default  col-xs-4  col-xs-offset-2">Effacer</button>

...
</from>
```

This does not work.

When I put it his way, the value of sender_control parameter is always "" when I submit via one of the 2 buttons.
However, if I position the hidden field AFTER the 2 buttons into the form, it works fine:

```
<form class="form-horizontal text-left" id = "form" action="SubmitMainForm" method="get">

...
    <button type="submit" name = "sender_control" id = "button_search" value = "button_search" class="btn btn-default col-xs-4">Rechercher</button>
                        <button type="submit" name = "sender_control" id = "button_delete" value = "button_delete" class="btn btn-default  col-xs-4  col-xs-offset-2">Effacer</button>

...
    <input type="hidden"  id="listbox_ii" name = "sender_control">
</from>
```

This works fine.

Could you explain me the reason? Why does the position of the hidden field change the behaviour?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, the successful controls in it will appear in the form data in that order.

A submit button will only be successful if is used to submit the form.

Your server side code is, apparently, ignoring subsequent values if they have the same name as an earlier one.

So if the hidden input appears before the buttons, then the value of `sender_control` will be the value of the hidden input.

If it appears after the buttons, the value of `sender_control` will be the button that you clicked.